# extracting text just after a particular tag using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to extract the text just after strong tag from html page given below? how can i do it using beautiful soup. It is causing me problem as it doesn't have any class or id so only way to select this tag is using text.

{strong}Name:{/strong} Sam smith{br}

Required result

Sam smith

Comment: post the html, your code and expected result

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all your answers but i was able to do this by following:

b_el = soup.find('strong',text='Name:')
print b_el.next_sibling

This works fine for me. This prints just next sibling how can i print next 2 sibling is there anyway ?